# MS Access: Update a Linked List Box

Tags: ms-access

I have a list box on an MS Access 2010 form that has its contents generated by a query.  The list box lists new customer names; these names are the ones that are not listed in the Customers table in the DB.

The user can select a customer name on the list box and click a button to add that customer name to the Customers table.

Now, after the new customer is added to the Customers table, I want to refresh the table, i.e. I want to re-run the query that generates its contents.  Is there a way to do this in VBA or by setting a property?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Listboxes, comboboxes, and forms/subforms have a Requery method that should refresh/requery/reload the underlying recordset.

```
Me.Requery 'Requery Form
Me.Listbox1.Requery 'Requery Listbox
Me.ComboBox1.Requery 'Requery ComboBox
Me.SubformControlName.Form.Requery 'Requery a subform
```

Choose the correct one above and change it to match the name of your control. I think you should put it at the end of your code on your button_click() procedure. In some scenarios you will place this code on a control's AfterUpdate event.